# How to ensure valid path object is returned in Java

Tags: java, scala, path, jvm, akka-stream

I am going through the quickstart guide in the Akka Streams docs for Scala and in one of the examples they are using Akka Streams to write to a file.

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

import scala.concurrent.*

import akka.*
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.*
import akka.stream.scaladsl.*
import akka.util.ByteString
import java.nio.file.Paths

object StreamsQuickstart:
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("Quickstart")
    val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 100)

    // val done: Future[Done] = source.runForeach(println)

    val factorials = source.scan(BigInt(1))((acc, next) => acc * next)
    val result: Future[IOResult] =
      factorials.map(num => ByteString(s"$num\n")).runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("factorials.txt")))
```

This is the code from the Akka docs, but it won't compile since `Paths.get("factorials.txt")` returns a `java.nio.file.Path | Null` but `FileIO.toPath` only accepts a `Path` object as an argument. How can I ensure that a `Path` is returned from `Paths.get`?

I looked through the docs for `Paths` but I didn't see anything about ensuring that a non Null object is returned. Being from the Akka docs, the least I would expect is that code like this would compile.

Comment: Something does not add up. Paths.get returns a Path, or throws an exception. Edit and paste the compiler output that states "java.nio.file.Path | Null". @others please confirm so that, if so, we can flag appropriately this question.

Comment: `Found: java.nio.file.Path | Null, Required: java.nio.file.Path` I'm using openjdk version 1.8.0_392 and Scala 3.3.1 if that makes a difference

Comment: You enabled the explicit nulls feature. Which is why that is happening. Disable that feature, it is experimental and probably will be abandoned altogether in the future.

Comment: Or, if for some reason you cannot follow the Miguel's advice, implement a function (Path | Null) => Path, or, since it never returns a null, just typecast it with Paths.get("factorials.txt").asInstanceOf[Path]

Comment: Well rather than cast there is a method to go for `A | Null` to `A`, `.nn` I think, not sure, never used that failed attempt of broken and useless feature.

Comment: That solved it. Apparently [this g8 template](https://github.com/DevInsideYou/scala-seed.g8) automatically configures Scalac to use Implicit Null

Comment: @Miguel Yes, thanks. I saw it but didn't realize it was in the libraries. Anyway the difference is that, in case it can be and is null, typecasting just returns null as String, while .nn fires exception : tried to cast away nullability, but value is null". And of course the typecasted will fire an exception as soon as an action on no-null will be invoked.

Comment: And I agree:  Forcing the applying of Option(T | Null) could have had some sense, while this is less than useless.